# How to acces elements of a combination as arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I'm trying to access the elements of a list of combinations as arrays, to be able to manipulate the results of the combinations.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
comb = combinations_with_replacement([a, b, c, d], 2)

for i in list(comb): 
    print(i)
```

I have this code, the `a, b, c, d` variables aren't going to be those specific values.
This returns:

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 4)
```

I want to be able to access each of those combinations as a array to manipulate its elements, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a wrapper.

```
def wrapper_combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r):
    comb = combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)
    for item in comb:
        yield list(item)
```

Now you have a list of lists.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
comb = wrapper_combinations_with_replacement([a, b, c, d], 2)
for i in list(comb): 
    print(i)
```

The result is:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 4]
```

Or use `list`

```
list(wrapper_combinations_with_replacement([a, b, c, d], 2))
```

And the result:

```
[[1, 1],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [1, 4],
 [2, 2],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 4],
 [3, 3],
 [3, 4],
 [4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comb_list = [list(combination) for combination in (list(comb))]
```

This will give you a list of combinations as arrays

```
for array_combination in comb_list:
    print(array_combination)

Output:

> [1, 1]
  [1, 2]
  [1, 3]
  [1, 4]
  [2, 2]
  [2, 3]
  [2, 4]
  [3, 3]
  [3, 4]
  [4, 4]
```